# Position navigation from bootstrap left and right from an image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

currently not knowing how to continue. I got an absolute positioned div element at the bottom of the page. I want to place a logo which is centered  and also left and right from the logo i want to place  the navigation ( i am working with bootstrap ). Here is an image from my idea so you can get a better view:

[image: Example]

Here is my code of the position absolute div at the bottom. I kinda lost it pretty fast and appreciate every help i can get!

```
<div id="footmenu">
    <div class="container navresize">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navleft">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Über uns</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                    <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" /></a>
                  </ul>


                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#footmenu {
    background:grey;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
 }
```

( I deleted the rest of the css because i was pretty sure that it was wrong )

Again thanks for the help and i appreciate your time !

Edit: Will update the jsfiddle now. Here is a result i found which shows perfectly what i want to get: http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/39221.html

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Su6VF/2/embedded/result/

Comment: Here OP: http://jsfiddle.net/Su6VF/ - Modify this according to your needs

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do though

Comment: Thanks alot @Ani! I will modify yours. I just found a site which shows just the result i wanted to have: http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/39221.html Though i want to work with bootstrap this is the result i want to get!

Comment: Here is the same jsfiddle with a place holder image: http://jsfiddle.net/Su6VF/1/

Comment: Haha thanks Jason! I need little bit more time because this is my first time working with jsfiddle. Also confusing for me to see the code in a small window. I appreciate your help thanks!

Comment: I tried to do it without the navbar first but it seems that it's not centered in the div. http://jsfiddle.net/Su6VF/2/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `inline-block` display for the `div`s containing the list items and the logo and `text-align:center` to the wrapping div to position these in the center.

Check this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/AKYmn/1/)

This might help you. Here is the styles used

```
.row{
    text-align:center;
}

.col-md-4{
    display:inline-block;
    float:none;
    width:auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot will try this tomorrow !